# DynamicLinq : how to use custom class method without class name to ParseLambda

Tags: lambda, expression, dynamic-linq, dynamic-linq-core

I'm using `DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(ParsingConfig, ....)`

which excepts `ParsingConfig` where we can specify custom class to use its method in expression, which can be parsed as valid `LambdaExpression`

I've registered custom static class in `ParsingConfig` by `CustomTypeProvider` and can parse lambda expression as well.

but I need to create expression as `StaticClassName.Method(input)`

Is there any way where I can register my static class methods so I can call method directly directly without specifying class name? like `Method(input)` in expression?

As DynamicLinq support many custom functions like `iif(x, y, z)` which are available to use in expression directly as inbuilt method

Reference: https://dynamic-linq.net/expression-language

so was thinking if it provide any way to register custom class method, by which we can just use method name in expression or not?

Please let me know if there is any other way with/without DynamicLinq which allows such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Did you annotate your static class with the `[DynamicLinqType]` attribute?

Example:

```cs
[DynamicLinqType]
public static class Utils
{
    public static int ParseAsInt(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
             return 0;
        }

        return int.Parse(value);
    }

    public static int IncrementMe(this int values)
    {
        return values + 1;
    }
}
```

This is needed so that System.Linq.Dynamic.Core can handle these custom classes.

See also https://dynamic-linq.net/advanced-extending

Comment: even after annotating class with [DynamicLinqType] based on above DynamicLinq docs we can consume Utils class like `Utils.ParseAsInt(Value);` but my question is different, is it possible to use syntax like `ParseAsInt(Value);` like we can go with static namespace, so can use method directly without class name?